# Output a MONTH() from a date in a number format it comes out correctly, but as a written date it's wrong

Tags: excel, date, google-sheets, format

Ive got a large data set that im formatting for reports in a pivot table, one of the things i want to do is get the `MONTH()` from a date.

I can do this fine, but if i format the date to be displayed as a written month as opposed to a number it outputs incorrectly.

Sorry to as such a simple questions but im truly stumped by this one !

Ive made a spreadsheet of the issue here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y5uAU6kpgBrwv8mgBTfSq14ZprRbyAMb3iM4rV46g9E/edit#gid=0

Comment: The sample spreadsheet can expire; you really should have included sample data. Remember, your question is not just about yourself; it is also about helping many others in the future that can find your problem (and an appropriate answer) through this dialogue.

Comment: @Jeeped updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MONTH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MONTH-function-579A2881-199B-48B2-AB90-DDBA0EBA86E8) is returning a number between 1 and 12. That means that you are trying to get the month from 01-Jan-1900 to 12-Jan-1900.

Solution: just use `=A2` and format as `mmmm`. This retains the actual underlying date.

You could also use the [CHOOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHOOSE-function-fce63190-b514-48cc-a7ff-c1cdaaec0907) on the MONTH.

```
=choose(month(A2), "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
```

However, you lose the underlying raw date value.

Comment: Thanks @jeeped i had originally done `=a2` and formatted as `mmmm`,  the issue is that im then putting this data into a pivot table and if i do that it dosnt summaries the data by month correctly

Comment: See my recent addendum above.

Answer (score 2):

It shows January because 9 formatted as a date is the 9th of January 1900.
You can let Spreadsheets display the month name with the full date too so what you are doing is probably not even necessary, otherwise you can construct a date like this

```
=DATE(2016, MONTH(A1), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution when the requirement is to Group data using Month/Quarter in Pivot Table & the original data only contain a date column:

1. When creating a Pivot table add "Date" as one of the rows along with the values you want.
2. In the resulting Pivot table, right click on any date and hover over "create pivot date group" then choose "Month/Quarter" or any format relevant to your analysis.